# How to generate a crypttab?

Tags: debian, disk-encryption

I installed Debian 11 on a new machine. The root filesystem is on an nvme. To copy data over I also had an old ssd in the computer while installing. Both disks were encrypted. Debian install somehow welded the ssd into the system and after removing it, update-initramfs tool returned error, that the ssd was not found and that warned that nvme is not in crypttab.

```
cryptsetup: WARNING: target 'nvme0n1p3_crypt' not found in /etc/crypttab
cryptsetup: ERROR: Couldn't resolve device /dev/mapper/debianLT--vg-swap_1
```

The swap partition was in `/etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/resume` so I removed it there and the error disappeared. I also tried to add the UUID and device name of nvme0n1np3_crypt into crypttab but now I get a "source mismatch"

```
cryptsetup: ERROR: nvme0n1p3_crypt: Source mismatch
```

My crypttab looks like this

```
nvme0n1p3_crypt UUID="Preipx-FT3v-3WDs-ZMF6-5W4A-3hOa-zXNt2r" none luks,discard
```

And my fstab

```
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=884b30b1-4235-4acd-9f06-1ff832e97970 /boot           ext2    defaults        0       2
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=C778-5F11  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-swap_1 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

blkid returns:

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="C778-5F11" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="b94b4299-d595-4f59-90eb-0848982907ee"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="884b30b1-4235-4acd-9f06-1ff832e97970" BLOCK_SIZE="1024" TYPE="ext2" PARTUUID="603666ed-d0e7-487f-9601-9ca8a99fe4c5"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="fc1cba48-eafe-4be7-a29b-e089d044e9c2" TYPE="crypto_LUKS" PARTUUID="c14adbc7-34fc-45f2-a554-9a1e8746357f"
/dev/mapper/nvme0n1p3_crypt: UUID="Preipx-FT3v-3WDs-ZMF6-5W4A-3hOa-zXNt2r" TYPE="LVM2_member"
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-root: UUID="f781f73f-5da1-4a57-a9b9-f5f5b87cdf5d" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/mapper/debian--vg-swap_1: UUID="989b506d-0b87-4802-bc1e-d9be466f122f" TYPE="swap"
```

The UUID `fc1cba48-eafe-4be7-a29b-e089d044e9c2` does not work either:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64
E: /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hooks/fuse failed with return 1.
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-16-amd64 with 1.
```

So how can I generate a new crypttab with the correct device in it?

Comment: Did you look at the [examples in the man page](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crypttab.5.html#EXAMPLES)?

Comment: I don't know what to use from there

Comment: So which UUID is the right one, nvme0n1p3 or nvme0n1p3_crypt?